# Raspberry Pi DesktopでClam AVを使ってフルスキャンしようとしたのですが、エラーが発生します

Tags: raspberry-pi

**現象**
Raspberry Pi DesktopでClam AVを使ってフルスキャンしようとしたのですが、bashで下記のエラーで中断されました。

```
=========================================
2020年 11月 22日 日曜日 08:15:59 JST
raspberrypi
LibClamAV Error: cli_tgzload: File daily.ldb not correctly loaded
LibClamAV Error: Can't load /var/lib/clamav/daily.cld: Malformed database
LibClamAV Error: cli_loaddbdir(): error loading database /var/lib/clamav/daily.cld
ERROR: Malformed database
```

**期待値**
ClamAVでフルスキャンを完了させる

**再現手順**
下記のシェルスクリプトを書き込んだファイルを作る

```
#!/bin/sh
echo =========================================
date
hostname
clamscan / \
     --infected \
     --recursive \
     --log=/var/log/clamav/clamscan.log \
     --move=/var/log/clamav/virus \
     --exclude-dir=^/boot \
     --exclude-dir=^/sys \
     --exclude-dir=^/proc \
     --exclude-dir=^/dev \
     --exclude-dir=^/var/log/clamav/virus

# --infected 感染を検出したファイルのみを結果に出力
# --recursive 指定ディレクトリ以下を再帰的に検査 圧縮ファイルは解凍して検査
# --log=FILE ログファイル
# --move=DIR 感染を検出したファイルの隔離先
# --remove 感染を検出したファイルを削除
# --exclude=FILE 　　検査除外ファイル（パターンで指定）
# --exclude-dir=DIR　検査除外ディレクトリ（パターンで指定）

if [ $? = 0 ]; then
  echo "ウイルス未検出."
else
  echo "ウイルス検出!!"
fi
```

実行権限を与える

```
$ sudo chmod +x /opt/script/clam-full.sh
```

ウイルス隔離用のフォルダを作る

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/log/clamav/virus
```

実行する

```
$ sudo /opt/script/clam-full.sh
```

**今まで試したこと・調べたこと**
`freshclam` を実行したところ、下記のエラーを吐いた

```
ERROR: /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log is locked by another process
ERROR: Problem with internal logger (UpdateLogFile = /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log).
ERROR: initialize: libfreshclam init failed.
ERROR: Initialization error!
```

`cli_tgzload: File daily.ldb not correctly loaded` で検索をかけてみたが、有効な情報は得られなかった

Comment: `freshclam.conf` の内容も追記してみてください。 / 恐らく freshclam はデーモンモードで既に動いているので手動実行は必要ありません。(もしくは crontab からの実行に切り替える)

Comment: 似たような事例がありました。[Something Wrong? ERROR: Failed to load new database](http://forums.clamwin.com/viewtopic.php?p=17905) こちらは `daily.ndb` ですけれども。

Comment: @metropolis リンク先を参考に`/var/lib/clamav/daily.cld`を削除したら無事に動きました！

Comment: @cubick `freshclam.conf`の内容を追記しました。具体的には`Database Mirror`を追記しました。

Answer (score 1):

`/var/lib/clamav/daily.cld`を削除しました。

すると、スキャンを完了させることに成功しました。
ありがとうございました！

```
----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 4564997
Engine version: 0.102.4
Scanned directories: 11650
Scanned files: 106891
Infected files: 0
Data scanned: 6151.45 MB
Data read: 5793.59 MB (ratio 1.06:1)
Time: 1876.573 sec (31 m 16 s)
ウイルス未検出.
```